# Java Mail Connection Refused when Using a domain mail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

Hi I recently got a domain mail. While I am able to send and receive mail through their portal, I am having problems doing so through Java Mail.
I am using the following configuration :

```
static {
        mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        //mailSender.setHost("smtp.net4india.com");
        mailSender.setHost("smtp8.net4india.com");
        mailSender.setUsername("xxxx");
        mailSender.setPassword("xxxx");
        mailSender.setPort(25);
        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String subject, String testMessage){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("xxxx");
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(testMessage);
        mailSender.send(message);

   }
```

I am still getting an exception like :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp8.net4india.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
```

I called the customer care and they said use smtp8.net4india.com as host, i tried the same.
He also said not to prvide any security settings, or configure it to null. Similar setting work          when i tried sending mail through gmail. I can access through outlook though
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Remove `mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` and try again. Maybe their SMTP server sucks and doesn't support SSL.

Comment: Yes I tried that. Dosent work. Even tried removing
 javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

But it gives relay not permitted

Comment: For most of the mail server, port 25 is for plain text connection. Port 465 is for SSL.

Comment: tried 465, 527 dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Not all of your failures have the same cause.  If you changed something and it failed in a different way, that doesn't mean your change was wrong, it just means you got past one problem and ran into another.

You need to [remove all the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  The rest you still need.  If that fails, post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing the new failure.

Comment: After i remove all the socket stuff i get the following error.
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 relay not permitted

Comment: See this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay).  Does your message have a From address?  What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 relay not permitted
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 relay not permitted

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1835)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1098)

Comment: That's the exception stack trace.  I'd still like to see the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void sendMail(MailInfo mailInfo) throws Exception{

    MyAuthenticator auth=null;
    Properties prop=mailInfo.getProperties();

    if(mailInfo.isValidate()){
        auth=new MyAuthenticator(mailInfo.getUsername(), mailInfo.getPassword());
    }

    Session mailSess=Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, auth);

    try {
        Message msg=new MimeMessage(mailSess);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailInfo.getFromAddress(),mailInfo.getSender()));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailInfo.getToAddress()));
        msg.setSubject(mailInfo.getSubject());
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(mailInfo.getContent());

        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}

public class MailInfo {

private String mailServerHost;
private String mailServerPort;
private String fromAddress;
private String sender;
private String toAddress;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean isValidate=false;
private String subject;
private String content;

public Properties getProperties(){
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", this.mailServerHost);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", this.mailServerPort);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", this.isValidate?"true":"false");
    return prop;
}
 .....getXXX(){...};
 .....setXXX(...){...};
}
```